# Tension of string suspending a ball in Circular motion, given the mass of ball, radius and length of string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

Ok so I have this question where a ball is suspended by an inextensible string and is caused to rotate in a horizontal circle which has its centre vertically below the point of suspension.

What would be the formula for the resultant of these forces, they have provided the values for the mass of the ball, length of the string and the radius?

Here is the diagram attached:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For circular motion $\sum F=ma_\textrm{cp}$ (centripetal force) (where $a_\textrm{cp}=v^2/r$ is the centripetal acceleration). You can divide the forces in to horizontal and vertical components. As the circular motion is in the horizontal plane, the equations are the following:

- $\sum F_\textrm{horizontal}=ma_\textrm{cp}$
- $\sum F_\textrm{vertical}=0$

Where the gravitational force is vertical, and the string force is paralell to the string. (The string force has both vertical and horizontal components.)

Answer (score 0):

You should make more of an effort to solve the problem yourself before asking for a complete solution here.

That said, an object that moves in a circle must have a resultant centripetal force corresponding to that motion. Once you know that force, you can figure out what the components must be that make it up.

Answer (score 0):

Your figure needs another angular coordinate for the circular motion in the horizontal circle (typically called $\phi$ in spherical or cylindrical polar coordinates), and that is the only coordinate that is changing with time ($r$ and $\theta$ are constant).  You can evaluate the forces in cylindrical polar coordinates considering gravity in the vertical direction and resolving tension into vertical and radial directions.  The only acceleration is in the radial direction due to the centripetal force required for circular horizontal motion.   As @fanyul pointed out in a comment, you can calculate $\dot \phi$ from the information given (considering the forces).

Your physics text should provide the complete relationship for acceleration in cylindrical polar coordinates; here you have a simple case .

Comment: You don't have to deal with polar coordinates. (Unless you have to give a formula for the time dependent spatial coordinates of the body.) And the angular velocity can be calculated based on the given parameters.

Comment: @fanyul  Yes, thanks for the correction.  I will edit my rsponse accordingly.